# Python code to remove records with two or more empty fields

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove records which have 2 or more NaNs, but so far all the code I have found online is either for removing one NaN or not relevant to this situation (e.g. Thresh, any and all).

The code I use for at least 1 NaN is df_exercise.isnull().any(axis=1).

I’m not sure how to adapt this specifically to 2 or more NaNs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to success is to count *NaN* cases in each row and check whether
it is less than your threshold.
You can get it running:

```
df_exercise.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 2
```

And to drop rows exceeding this threshold (keep rows within the threshold),
run:

```
df_exercise = df_exercise[df_exercise.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You count the number of empty fields per row and only keep those with fewer than 2 empty fields.

```py
keep = df_exercise.isnull().sum(axis=1).lt(2)
df_exercise[keep]
```